# SSL certificate for kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kibana, opensearch

I'm trying to configure my `OpenSearch` domain to `Kibana`,

I'm using `ec2` as a `Kibana tunnel` and creating a proxy with a publicly accessible endpoint.

All my configuration is good except for my SSL certificate.
I created an SSL certificate with `Open SSL`, I know it is not secured but I'm trying to understand what is the best way to create a certificate or even there is another way? (Some AWS service)
I tried to use `CloudFront` and it failed.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by configuring opensearch domain to kibana? Also what is kibana tunnel..? Also what cloudfront has to do with creating certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AWS Certificate Manager` to create certificate. If you will use your certificate in AWS services, it will be very useful, and also, it's free. The biggest problem is that you can't export it and use it anywhere else other than AWS. Also you can import your own certificate to Certificate Manager. The expiration dates of the certificates that is created via ACM (AWS Certificate Manager) is managed by AWS itself. But if you bring your own certificates to ACM, you should manage expiration dates.

Reference : https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/

Comment: I need to use it in a ec2 instance that functions as a tunnel so as you said exporting is not an option